# Google Analytis for visitors

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I woudlike show for my visitors stats from Google Analytics.
In all articles I found is about I must login before get Analytics data, yes it's ok, but
I would like display stats for my visitors, when they havn't Google account.
How do this?

Maybe by API key?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a [Service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and fetching the data for your site once a day.  Then you will be able to display this data to your users.   The reason i suggest that you store the data is that the data will never change and there is a (quota) limited number of requests you can make each day.

If you tell us what language you are planing to do this in i may be able to help with some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, I will build this in PHP:)

Comment: @DalmTo: Can I login withoud Library?

Comment: Yup you can make all the calls manually they are just http requests

Comment: I can do this with window prompt, but How do this like service account?

Comment: Windows prompt running php?  You may want to open a different question the two really arn't related.

Comment: @DalmTo: I show my code on http://pastebin.com/3CdVHZhv
I would like get this data without google window approve and without other libraries, clean simplest code. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics Super Proxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) allows you to show data from your Google Analytics account to users even if they aren't logged in.  It works by setting up an API token before hand then generating a public URL you can use to load into your application.